# limits of $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x\sin{1/x}+y}{x+y}$

Tags: limits

How to calculate this limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}+y}{x+y}$$
I have found that 
$$|\frac{x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}+y}{x+y}|\leq1$$
but I can't conclude.

Comment: Hint: Try taking the limit along lines to the origin (such as $x=0$, $y=0$, or $y=mx$).

Comment: Take the line $y=0$. Then $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}+y}{x+y}=\lim_{x\to0}\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$$

Comment: Then, there is no limit?

Comment: @TheoryNombre Nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x=y $.

It becomes

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sin (\frac {1}{x})+1  }{2}$$

if $x=\frac {1}{n\pi} $, we find $\frac {1}{2}$

and if
$x=\frac {1}{ \frac {\pi}{2}+2n\pi  }$, we find $1$.

the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @TheoryNombre not at all friend of the  world.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't exist:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}\frac{x\sin\frac1x+y}{x+y}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin\frac1x}x=\lim_{x\to0}\sin\frac1x$$

If it doesn't exist along one path, it doesn't exist at all.